# How to remove item from array using localStorage.removeItem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, storage

I'm using `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` to store data (devices, in my case) from an API to persist through page resets. When a device is clicked on, it gets stored into a shopping bag. When the user clicks a device in the bag, I want it to be able to "delete" and be removed from the local storage.
Right now it work so that on the UI it shows that it's being removed, but when the page refreshes it comes back because it's still in the localStorage.

I've tried to use `localStorage.removeItem(deviceTitle)` in my `removeDevice` function, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is this because I have the `localStorage.getItem` in the `componentDidMount`? If so, how do I go about changing that so the `removeItem` function will work?

`addDevice()` is called during by onClick function (please let me know if you need to see that portion of the code)

```
  addDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
    const array = Array.from(this.state.bag);
    if (array.indexOf(deviceTitle) === -1) {
      array.push(deviceTitle);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(array));
    this.setState({
      bag: array
    });
  };
```

Here is where the the device is supposed to be removed from local storage

```
removeDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      bag: prevState.bag.filter(d => d !== deviceTitle)
    }));
    localStorage.removeItem(deviceTitle);
  };
```

and this is my componentDidMount() where the devices get stored

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.search("");
    const storedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
    console.log(storedList);
    const bag = storedList;
    this.setState({ bag });
  }
```

EDIT more code added below:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search for devices..."
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          {this.state.devices.map(device => (
            <ul key={device.title}>
              <p>
                {device.title}{" "}
                <i
                  className="fas fa-plus"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "green" }}
                  onClick={e => this.addDevice(e, device.title)}
                />
              </p>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </form>
        {this.state.bag.map(device => (
          <p key={device.title}>
            {device}
            <i
              className="fas fa-times"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "red" }}
              onClick={e => this.removeDevice(e, device)}
            />
          </p>
        ))}
        <button onClick={e => this.removeAll(e)}>Remove all</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are screenshots of how it looks:
[items in local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucIr2.png),
[items after being removed in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oVFc.png)
but when I reset the page, it reverts back to the first image because the devices weren't removed from localStorage

Comment: In most cases `setState` doesn't immediately update the state, so you should update `localStorage` in its callback argument, see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#setstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the array after removing the item itself

```
removeDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      bag: prevState.bag.filter(d => d !== deviceTitle)
    }));
    // actual localStorage item removing 
        let devicesArray  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"))
        devicesArray.splice(devicesArray.indexOf(deviceTitle), 1)
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(devicesArray));
  };
```

because setting item if it's there it replace it's value check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Can you possibly tell me what the .splice function is doing?

Comment: it's removing an element from array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the item `list` to your array of devices. But if you delete it, you try to delete the devicename.

The way you could remove an item would be to remove it from the array and then call `localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(array));` with array being without that element you want to remove.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Comment: Ohh okay I think I was thinking too deeply about it. I tried it and this works, but for some reason doesn't delete the last item I click. Do you know why that might be? For example I have: Airpods, Macbook, iPhone and I delete iPhone then Macbook, but when I reset the page, Macbook is still there.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already filtering the data and updating the state, you can add the second argument for `setState` which is a callback. In your callback, you can get the updated bag from your state and set it to replace the value in localStorage.

You can do it this way

```
removeDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    bag: prevState.bag.filter(d => d !== deviceTitle)
  }), () => {
    const { bag } = this.state;
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(bag))
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it this way and for some reason does not let me remove the last device...do you know why this might be? I have updated my question to include more code if needed.